# JQ — Return first element that satisfies a predicate

Tags: json, jq

I have a string like:

```json
"The sky is blue."
```

and a JSON file like

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "name": "Entry 1",
    "keywords": [
      "orange",
      "yellow"
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "id": 2345,
    "name": "Entry 2",
    "keywords": [
      "red",
      "blue",
      "pink"
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "id": 3456,
    "name": "Entry 3",
    "keywords": [
        "green",
        "blue",
        "black"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to return the first element which has a keyword that can be found in the string.

In this case I would like to have the element with the id `2345`, because the keyword `"blue"` occurs in the string, and it is the first match.

Is there a one-line solution with JQ (e.g. with various pipes)? I'm not looking for a solution with loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation based on Inian's excellent answer:

```
first(.[] | select(.keywords | any(inside("the sky is blue."))))
```

If we have the data in `input.json` and the string `"the sky is blue."` passed as a parameter we have:

```
jq --arg str 'the sky is blue' 'first(.[] | select(.keywords | any(inside($str))))' input.json
```

This returns the first element which keywords is contained within `$str`:

```json
{
  "id": 2345,
  "name": "Entry 2",
  "keywords": [
    "red",
    "blue",
    "pink"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`first/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#first(expr),last(expr),nth(n;expr)) with a `select` expression is the right approach here

```
jq --arg v "The sky is blue." 'first(.[] | select(.keywords as $k | $v | match($k[])))'
```

produces

```json
{
  "id": 2345,
  "name": "Entry 2",
  "keywords": [
    "red",
    "blue",
    "pink"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

with the above content in the `input.json`

query:

```
 jq '.[] | {id, keywords: .keywords[]} | select(.keywords == "blue") ' input.json
```

output:

```
{
  "id": 2345,
  "keywords": "blue"
}
{
  "id": 3456,
  "keywords": "blue"
}
```

you can get the first object from this.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Yes this works when I know that I'm looking for the value "blue". But as stated in my question, I would like that each keyword is checked whether it is in the string or not... the solution should check orange, yellow, red, blue ... and then stop because blue can be found in the string